# Найти в тексте слова, которые есть в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе данных есть таблица `slovo`, ее структура:

```
id - auto_increment 
name - само слово( уникальный )
```

Есть переменная: **$text**, которая содержит в себе некий текст.

В таблице `slovo` есть запись: id = 1, name = Яблоко , id = 2, name = дерево

```
$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево.";
```

Вопрос: каким образом определить, есть ли в переменной слова, которые находятся в таблице `slovo`, и если есть, то эти слова выделить в `<span id="id_slovo">слово</span>` , где **id_slovo** - значение id для этого слова из базы.

P.S. Учитывая то, что может быть и словосочетания.

Буду очень благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Comment: база данных поддерживает SQL?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, Да, конечно, база mysql

Comment: морфологию русского языка надо учитывать?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, желательно конечно... Было бы здорово. Но не обязательно. Главное чтоб на регистр(заглавные, строчные) не обращало внимания, то сеть, слова яблоко и Яблоко - принимались как одно и тоже.

Comment: добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: Если это и вправду MySQL, я бы предложил создать ХП или ПФ для реализации (в зависимости от того, одиночную фразу надо обрабатывать или пакетно). Внутри - парсинг по словам в темп-таблицу, запрос, пересборка и возврат строки со вставленными тегами. Код в общем тривиальный. Игнор регистра - выбором соотв. коллации. Впрочем, если это совсем одноразовое действо, то можно и на стороне PHP, беды большой не будет. Особенно если он с MySQL на одном хосте.

Comment: @Денис Не забудьте указать, кому вы отдадите награду, иначе она пропадёт...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//Сначала нужно найти все слова, бьем фразу в массив по пробелам

$words = explode(' ', $text);

//Затем проверяем каждое слово:

foreach($words as $word) {

    $word = trim($word); //убираем пробелы

    //Проверяем в базе, любимым адаптером выполняя запрос
    //Само собой никто не мешает заменить ILIKE на LIKE или =
    $wordId = $msSql->fetchOne("SELECT id FROM slove WHERE name ILIKE '{$word}'");


    //Если в базе такое слово есть, то заменяем его в тексте на нужный span
   if (!empty($wordId)) {
      $text = str_replace($word, "<span id='$wordId'>$word</span>", $text);
   }

}
```

Comment: А как в таком случае быть со словосочетаниями?

Comment: Можно точно также, костылями. Берешь 2 слова последовательных, 3 слова последовательных, 4... в общем пока не надоест. Работать конечно будет, но очень плохо. Медленно и фраза "яблоко на дереве" не будет найдена если в базе есть "яблоки на дереве". Средствами mysql полнотекстовый поиск не знаю как решается, наверное никак. Если проект не старый, и подобный функционал полнотекстового поиска действительно нужен, то табличку со словами нужно перенести в postgres. Там нативные механизмы полнотекстового поиска, которые просто шикарно найдут "яблоко на дереве".

Comment: Да и в целом - postgres точно такой же как и mysql для начинающих, но там есть много крутых вещей которых нет в mysql. Это я не начинаю холивар если что :) И там и там много чего делал.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov, скажите пжл, а куда деваются запятые и точки из `$text` при  `explode` в массив? Вернее в массив они не попадают?

Comment: и каждый раз в цикле вы будете открывать коннект к бд... это не хорошо. во всяком случае в mysql.

Comment: будут заменены части слов, т.е. даже в данном тексте есть предлог "В" - после замены он будет писаться маленькими буквами и везде где эта буква будет встречаться, она будет обрамлена в теги, например слово "дерево" будет после замены выглядеть так "дере<span id='1'>в</span>о"

Comment: @TimurVI всякие знаки препинания можно отрезать в том месте где пробелы убираем, примерно так `$word = trim($word, [' ', ',', '.', ';']);`

Comment: @Alex коннект к базе данных остается один, для этого и нужны адаптеры. Более того - если использовать подготовленные запросы и кэширование, то скорость можно увеличить много кратно. Хотя это все равно очень криво подобным образом пытаться искать вхождения строк. Для поиска по тексту разработаны специальные алгоритмы, специальные индексы для лексем. Все это работает на порядки быстрее чем вот так вот как я написал делать. Sphynx или postgres уделают этот алгоритм и качественно и количественно на два порядка. Но он годится для домашней странички с базой данных, где таблица называется slovo :)

Comment: @DenisMatafonov а я было подумал, что Вы намерены в цикле каждый раз новый коннект открывать :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево.";

// все слова из таблицы, присутствующие в тексте получаем одним запросом
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM slovo
WHERE INSTR('" . mysql_escape_string($text) . "', name)");

// проходим по всем словам и делаем замену
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $text = str_ireplace($row['name'], 
        '<span id="word-' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</span>', 
        $text); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP MySQL PDO

Думаю что такое вот решение подойдет

```
    class ConnectPDO {

        private $connect = array(
            'login' => 'DB_USER',
            'password' => 'DB_PASS',
            'db' => 'slovo_db'
        );

        private $dbc;

        public function __construct() {
            $db_name=$this->connect['db'];
            $this->dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", $this->connect['login'], $this->connect['password']);
        }

    }

$connection=new ConnectPDO();

$sth = $connection->dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM `slovo` WHERE `name` LIKE %:name% ");



$data = array();


    $text = "asd  sad asd as dasd asd asdasdas das das das";

    //explode делает массив из фразы с которым далее очень просто работать
    $text_aray = explode(" ", $text);

    foreach ($text_aray as $each) { 

        $sth->execute(array('name'=>$each));

        $result = $sth->fetchAll();

        $data[] = $result;
    }

    // отобразить все слова из базы
    foreach ($data as $data_block){
        foreach ($data_block as $each_row){
            echo '<span id="'.$each_row['id'].'">'.$each_row['name'].'</span><br>';
        }
    }
```

параметры, которые нужно заменить на на свои:

```
DB_USER юзер mysql 
DB_PASS пароль mysql
slovo_db база mysql
```

Comment: открывать новый коннект в pdo в цикле очень плохая практика. это очень плохой пример использования подготовленного выражения. никогда так не делайте.

Comment: тогда можно просто создать подключение в __construct и использовать массив для передачи ` %:name% ",array('name'=>$each));` что есть best practice

Comment: это ни в коем случае не является best practice! Рекомендую еще раз почитать о принципах работы PDO. Не нужно готовить запрос повторно. Достаточно подготовить запрос лишь один раз и затем лишь передавать параметры. Вы же готовите запрос каждый раз в цикле.

Comment: правда. но уже без повторного подключения.согласен.

Comment: Вы не поняли. **1** - подключение к бд повторно делать не нужно, тем более в цикле(это вы поправили). **2**  -  **в pdo достаточно всего лишь один раз подготовить запрос и потом только подставлять параметры в подготовленный запрос.** А Вы зачем-то это делаете каждый раз.

Comment: @Alex Да, я исправил.

Comment: хоть и с третьей попытки, но теперь гораздо лучше

Comment: А так будет быстрее работать?

Comment: Вы не заметите разницы по скорости, разница в том, что Вы меньше затрачиваете ресурсов на запрос. И эта разница тем ощутимее, чем больше запросов идет на Ваш сервер.

Answer (score 3):

```
$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево.";
//заменяем несколько пустых символов на один (чтобы избежать ситуации, когда из-за нескольких пробелов сочетания не будут найдены)
$text = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $text);

//подключаемся к базе данных (на примере MYSQL, подправите под свою базу) и выбираем
// все слова из таблицы, присутствующие в тексте получаем одним запросом, сортируем по уменьшению длины слов (фраз).
// Это нужно, чтобы исключить вариант когда при наличии 2-х слов/фраз "яблоко", "лежит яблоко" после замены первого,
// второе не получится уже заменить, так как между ними уже будет span
try{
$link = new PDO(   'mysql:host=your-hostname;dbname=your-db;charset=utf8mb4',
                    'your-username',
                    'your-password',
                    array(
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
                    )
                );

$handle = $link->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM slovo WHERE INSTR(?, name) ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name) DESC');
$handle->bindValue(1, $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$handle->execute();
$result = $handle->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

// проходим по всем словам и делаем замену
foreach($result as $row){

  //экранируем служебные символы " . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - "
  $word = preg_quote($row->name);

  //используем регулярное выражение чтобы:
  //1) после замены регистр слов не был изменён
  //2) были заменены полностью слова а не только вхождения, например при слове "дерево", слово "деревообработка" останутся не тронутыми

  $text = preg_replace('/(^|\W)(' . $word . ')($|\W)/iu',  '\\1<span id="word-' . $row->id . '">\\2</span>\\3', $text);
}
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    print($ex->getMessage());
}
```

если вы хотите использовать морфологию (например библиотеку phpMorphy), то я бы рекомендовал:

1) если количество записей в таблице slovo не большое, делать полную выборку

$handle = $link->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM slovo ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(name) DESC');
$handle->execute();

2) если количество записей в таблице slovo большое, то для уменьшения времени замены добавить в таблицу slovo столбик, в который помещать корень слова (можно автоматически через библиотеку) и по нему делать фильтрацию     INSTR(?, new_column).

3) После при переборе слов перед

```
$word = preg_quote($row->name);
```

## сделать загрузку всех вариантов слова, а после сделать preg_replace для каждого варианта.

Решение не оформлялось в виде класса, так как, насколько я понимаю, это  будет частью вашей задачи. здесь сосредоточено только на основных моментах.

Comment: А если `name` будет содержать один из служебных символов RegEx?

Comment: @P.Fateev добавлено экранирование служебных символов с помощью preg_quote

Comment: если ставите минусы, то пожалуйста  пишите за что, возможно это очень просто исправить....

Answer (score 0):

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89103534a0656d58422553a295374da1c0a72da1)

```
 <?php
  # there is no information about where this text is from... we have it in
  # varriable $text
  $text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево.";

  #one row result from mysqli_fetch_assoc
  $replacement_arr = array("id"=>1, "name"=>"яблоко"); 

  echo 'before:'.$text."\n\t";
  f_process_text($text, $replacement_arr);
  echo 'after:'.$text."\n";


  function f_process_text(&$text, $replacement_arr){
     #set morphological phrases for $replacement_arr["name"];
     $phrases = f_get_phrases($replacement_arr["name"]); 
     list($patterns, $replacements) = f_get_prepared_fo_replacement_arrs($phrases, $replacement_arr["id"]);
     $text = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacements, $text);
  }

  #return array
  function f_get_phrases($words){
    $result = array();
    $result[] = $words;

    #to add phrases it is recomended to use [phpMorphy](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/)

    return $result;
  }

  function f_get_prepared_fo_replacement_arrs($phrases, $id){
      $patterns = array();
      $replacements = array();
      foreach($phrases as $phrase){
          $patterns[] = '/'.$phrase.'/';
          $replacements[] = '<span id="'.$id.'">'.$phrase.'</span>';
      }
      return array($patterns, $replacements);
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой касс у меня вышел:

```
<?php

/**
 * Поиск и замена фраз в строке
 * User: Rochfort
 */
class PhrasesReplacement
{
    /**
     * Текст
     * @var string
     */
    protected $text;
    /**
     * Массив фраз для замены
     * @var array
     */
    protected $phrases;
    /**
     * Массив подстрок для замены
     * @var array
     */
    protected $patterns = [];
    /**
     * Массив подстрок на замену
     * @var array
     */
    protected $replacements = [];

    /**
     * PhrasesReplacement constructor.
     * @param string $text
     * @param array $phrases
     */
    public function __construct(string $text = '', array $phrases = [])
    {
        if (!empty($text)) {
            $this->text = $text;
        }
        if (!empty($phrases)) {
            $this->phrases = $phrases;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получить текст с заменами
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReplacedText()
    {
        if (empty($this->patterns) || empty($this->replacements)) {
            list($this->patterns, $this->replacements) = $this->getPatterns();
        }
        return preg_replace( $this->patterns, $this->replacements, $this->text);
    }

    /**
     * Формируем массивы для поиска и замены
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPatterns() {
        $patterns = [];
        $replacements = [];

        foreach ($this->phrases as $phrase) {
            $name = preg_quote($phrase['name']);
            $patterns[] = '/('.$name.')/iu';
            $replacements[] = '<span id="'.$phrase['id'].'">$1</span>';
        }

        return [$patterns, $replacements];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $text
     * @return PhrasesReplacement
     */
    public function setText(string $text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPhrases()
    {
        return $this->phrases;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $phrases
     * @return PhrasesReplacement
     */
    public function setPhrases(array $phrases)
    {
        $this->patterns = [];
        $this->replacements = [];
        $this->phrases = $phrases;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Работать с ним так:

```
$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево.";
$phrases = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'корзине лежит'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'дерево'],
];

$replacer = new PhrasesReplacement($text,$phrases);
echo $replacer->getReplacedText() . "\n";

$text2 = "В корзине ЛеЖаТ Яблоки. В поле стоит дерево.";
echo $replacer->setText($text2)->getReplacedText() . "\n";

$phrases = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'лежат яблоки']
];
echo $replacer->setPhrases($phrases)->getReplacedText() . "\n";
```

Ну и соответственно из базы удобнее всего будет получать значения так:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `slovo`;';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->execute();

$phrases = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Один вариант**:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...';
$user = '...';
$password = '...';

$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево."; // исходная строка
$max_count_of_replace = count(explode(' ', $text)); // максимальное кол-во замен в исходной строке

$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Ошибка: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `slovo` WHERE INSTR(:text, `name`)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// заменяем слова из таблицы, присутствующие в $text

$count_of_replace = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $text = str_ireplace($row['name'], "<span id=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</span>", $text, $count);

    $count_of_replace += $count;
    if ($count_of_replace > $max_count_of_replace) {
        break;
    }
}

echo $text; // результат
```

Идея состоит в использовании MySQL-функции: `INSTR()` + добавлено ограничение на максимальное кол-во замен.

**Второй вариант**:

Не используем `INSTR()`, например, если хочется независимости от СУБД.

```php
<?php

// параметры подключения
// ...

$text = "В корзине лежит яблоко. В поле стоит дерево."; // исходная строка
$max_count_of_replace = count(explode(' ', $text)); // максимальное кол-во замен в исходной строке

$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Ошибка: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `slovo`;';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$count_of_replace = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    $text = str_ireplace($row['name'], "<span id=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</span>", $text, $count);

    $count_of_replace += $count;
    if ($count_of_replace > $max_count_of_replace) {
        break;
    }
}

echo $text; // результат
```